# deleting old files using crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I use the following crontab record in order to daily backup my DB:

```
0 2 * * * MYSQL_PWD=password mysqldump -u user db_name > $HOME/db_backups/db_name-$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M).sql 2>> $HOME/db_backups/cron.log
```

I want to add another crontab record that will delete the DB dumps that are older then one month.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @knittle logrotate is for logs (?)

Comment: While logrotate can delete files of a certain age, it only operates on files that it rotates; not a typical scenario for a db backup.  Of course you can add the `find ... -exec rm {} \;` command (documented in other answers) as a script within the logrotate configuration.  This may be useful in some cases; [example in last entry of a conversation thread on another forum](http://www.directadmin.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-3654.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just create another cron:

```
0 3 * * * find $HOME/db_backups -name "db_name*.sql" -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \; >> $HOME/db_backups/purge.log 2>&1
```

It will find all backups older than 30 days and delete them.

Comment: Can we write the filenames that will be deleted to a file for reference.

Comment: Sure, you can either use `rm -v` or `find -print` to output the names of the files that are being deleted.

Answer (score 27):

```
find /db_backups/ -mtime +30 -delete
```

This command would delete DB backups older than 30 days.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool called `tmpreaper` that securely deletes files matching certain criteria, such as an access or modification date *n* days in the past.