# Deleting oldest files with shell

Tags: shell

I have a folder /var/backup where a cronjob saves a backup of a database/filesystem. It contains a latest.gz.zip and lots of older dumps which are names timestamp.gz.zip.
The folder ist getting bigger and bigger and I would like to create a bash script that does the following:

- Keep latest.gz.zip
- Keep the youngest 10 files
- Delete all other files

Unfortunately, I'm not a good bash scripter so I have no idea where to start. Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [deleting old files using crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375409/deleting-old-files-using-crontab)

Comment: @tripleee No, deleting files older than a certain time is very different from deleting the N oldest file

Comment: See [Shell script for moving oldest files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22674) and [Bash, remove oldest files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35792)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn to use the [`find`](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm) command, possibly with `xargs`, that is something similar to

```
 find /var/backup -type f -name 'foo' -mtime -20 -delete
```

or if your `find` doesn't have `-delete`:

```
 find /var/backup -type f -name 'foo' -mtime -20 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Of course you'll need to improve a lot, this is just to give ideas.

Comment: Cool thank you for the hint. I figured out that find /var/backup -mtime +3 -delete (files older than 3 days) is a good solution for me.

Comment: When going for the `xargs` version, you should definitely stick to the form `find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd`. This ensures proper treatment of filenames containing whitespace. `-print0` tells `find` to emit matches terminated by a NULL character and `-0` tells `xargs` that the NULL character is the delimiter.

Comment: Sticking to this form also minimizes security risks: http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Security-Considerations-for-xargs

Answer (score 2):

In zsh you can do most of it with expansion flags:

```
files=(*(.Om))
rm $files[1,-9]
```

Be careful with this command, you can check what matches were made with:

```
print -rl -- $files[1,-9]
```