# Clearing archive files with linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Here is my problem,

I have a folder where is stored multiple files with a specific format:

Name_of_file.TypeMM-DD-YYYY-HH:MM

where  MM-DD-YYYY-HH:MM is the time of its creation. There could be multiple files with the same name but not the same time of course.

What i want is a script that can keep the 3 newest version of each file.

So, I found one example there:
[Deleting oldest files with shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352040/deleting-oldest-files-with-shell)

But I don't want to delete a number of files but to keep a certain number of newer files. Is there a way to get that find command, parse in the Name_of_file and keep the 3 newest???

Here is the code I've tried yet, but it's not exactly what I need.

```
find /the/folder -type f -name 'Name_of_file.Type*' -mtime +3 -delete
```

Thanks for help!

---

So i decided to add my final solution in case anyone liked to get it. It's a combination of the 2 solutions given.

```
ls -r | grep -P "(.+)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}" | awk 'NR > 3' | xargs rm
```

One line, super efficiant. If anything changes on the pattern of date or name just change the grep -P pattern to match it. This way you are sure that only the files fitting this pattern will get deleted.

Comment: Is the file format fixed or can you change it? sorting `YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM` would be so much easier than `MM-DD-YYYY-HH:MM`.

Comment: yhea I could change it. It would actualy be easy

Comment: do you plan to use the file name to determine the 3 newest files?

Comment: I assumed that was the question. Did you want to use the actual mtime instead?

Comment: I don't really care, as long as I can get to my goal :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be extra, extra sure that the timestamp on the file is the exact same timestamp on the file name? If they're off a bit, do you care?

The `ls` command can sort files by timestamp order. You could do ***something*** like this:

```
$ ls -t | awk 'NR > 3' | xargs rm
```

- THe `ls -t` lists the files by modification time where the newest are first.
- The `awk 'NR > 3' prints out the list of files **except for the first three lines** which are the three newest.
- The `xargs rm` will remove the files that are older than the first three.

Now, this isn't the exact solution. There are possible problems with `xargs` because file names might contain weird characters or whitespace. If you can guarantee that's not the case, this should be okay.

Also, you probably want to group the files by name, and keep the last three. Hmm...

```
ls | sed 's/MM-DD-YYYY-HH:MM*$//' | sort -u | while read file
do
    ls -t $file* | awk 'NR > 3' | xargs rm
done
```

The ls will list all of the files in the directory. The `sed 's/\MM-DD-YYYY-HH:MM//' will remove the date time stamp from the files. The`sort -u` will make sure you only have the unique file names. Thus

```
file1.txt-01-12-1950
file2.txt-02-12-1978
file2.txt-03-12-1991
```

Will be reduced to just:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

These are placed through the loop, and the `ls $file*` will list all of the files that start with the file name and suffix, but will pipe that to `awk` which will strip out the newest three, and pipe that to `xargs rm` that will delete all but the newest three.

Comment: NICE! It worked perfectly. I had a couple of mistakes. One for every file not deleted. (rm: missing operand Try `rm --help' for more information.) I ll manage with it don't worry. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're using the date in the filename to date the archive file, and that is possible to change the date format to `YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM` (as established in comments above), here's a quick and dirty shell script to keep the newest `3` versions of each file within the present working directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
KEEP=3  # number of versions to keep

while read FNAME; do
    NODATE=${FNAME:0:-16}  # get filename without the date (remove last 16 chars)
    if [ "$NODATE" != "$LASTSEEN" ]; then  # new file found
        FOUND=1; LASTSEEN="$NODATE"
    else  # same file, different date
        let FOUND="FOUND + 1"
        if [ $FOUND -gt $KEEP ]; then
            echo "- Deleting older file: $FNAME"
            rm "$FNAME"
        fi
    fi
done < <(\ls -r | grep -P "(.+)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}")
```

Example run:

```
[me@home]$ ls
another_file.txt2011-02-11-08:05  
another_file.txt2012-12-09-23:13  
delete_old.sh
not_an_archive.jpg 
some_file.exe2011-12-12-12:11             
some_file.exe2012-01-11-23:11 
some_file.exe2012-12-10-00:11  
some_file.exe2013-03-01-23:11  
some_file.exe2013-03-01-23:12

[me@home]$ ./delete_old.sh 
- Deleting older file: some_file.exe2012-01-11-23:11
- Deleting older file: some_file.exe2011-12-12-12:11

[me@home]$ ls
another_file.txt2011-02-11-08:05
another_file.txt2012-12-09-23:13
delete_old.sh
not_an_archive.jpg
some_file.exe2012-12-10-00:11
some_file.exe2013-03-01-23:11
some_file.exe2013-03-01-23:12
```

Essentially, but changing the file name to dates in the form  to `YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM`, a normal string sort (such as that done by `ls`) will automatically group similar files together sorted by date-time.

The `ls -r` on the last line simply lists all files within the current working directly print the results in reverse order so newer archive files appear first.

We pass the output through `grep` to extract only files that are in the correct format.

The output of that command combination is then looped through (see the `while` loop) and we can simply start deleting after 3 occurrences of the same filename (minus the date portion).

Comment: I get this error when i try to run the script line 15: `done <(\ls -r | grep -P "(.+)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}")'

Comment: What's the error message? and you appear to be one `<` short. It should be `done < <(....)`

Answer (score 1):

This pipeline will get you the 3 newest files (by modification time) in the current dir

```
stat -c $'%Y\t%n' file* | sort -n | tail -3 | cut -f 2-
```

To get all *but* the 3 newest:

```
stat -c $'%Y\t%n' file* | sort -rn | tail -n +4 | cut -f 2-
```